nx build fails after npm install
I am building my Angular projects on my own Azure Devops Agent.
Therefore I need the following commands:

npm install (to create node_modules folder)
nx build (to build my angular project in the dist-directory)
...

Since a while this process fails after npm install with the following error message:

Failed to process project graph. Run "nx reset" to fix this

And indeed: This command resolves the issue, so if I run nx reset inbetween the nx build works.
But of course I do not want to live with this error mesaage.
I already tried to disable the cache for build in the nx.json:
  "build": {
     "cache": false,
     "dependsOn": ["^build"],
     "inputs": ["production", "^production"]
  },

But this setting has also no effect.
Any ideas what I could try?
